# image not changing on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I apologise if it sounds similar to a previous question, but I've gone over those similar questions and I still can't figure out what the problem is with my code. it's petty simple yet it doesn't work.
I have an image. I want it to change to a second image when I click on it, and to a third image when I click on the second image. and then, I want it to change back to the first image when the third image is clicked.

html:

```
           <img id="narrow" class="item" src="images/joe2.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="changeImage(this);">
```

javascipt:

```
  function changeImage(imgl) {
       if(imgl.src=="images/joe2.jpg") {
            imgl.src="images/stray_cat.jpg"; 
       }
       else if (imgl.src=="images/stray_cat.jpg") {
            imgl.src="images/mathewgarber.jpg"; 
       }
       else // (imgl.src=="images/mathewgarber.jpg") {
            imgl.src="images/joe2.jpg";
       }
  }
```

what happens is that nothing happens when I click on the first image. thanks for your help.

Comment: What errors do you get? Is the function even called? Is your script loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dsfq above said, the image src url will be relative, including the site host.

```
function changeImage(imgl) {
        if (imgl.src.indexOf('images/joe2.jpg') > -1) {        
            imgl.src = "images/stray_cat.jpg";
        } else if (imgl.src.indexOf("images/stray_cat.jpg") > -1) {
            imgl.src = "images/mathewgarber.jpg";
        } else // (imgl.src=="images/mathewgarber.jpg")
        {
            imgl.src = "images/joe2.jpg";
        }
    }
```

If you have your heart set on your method, you can use a indexOf check to determine if the image name is part of the full src url.

Comment: thank you, joey - it's working. but can you please explain what the -1 is for? I'm guessing it's a way of checking whether the condition is "true"?

Comment: indexOf returns the position within a string that matches the argument.  If no match is found, it will always return a -1.  It views a string as an array of characters that is 0 based.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var images = [
    'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1',
    'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2',
    'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3'
],
i = 0;

function changeImage(img) {
    img.src = images[++i % images.length];
}
```

Comparing image `src` with a string is not very reliable because it can contain full domain and protocol. Instead you can store images in array and use `%` operator which is very useful for such kind of cycling.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/phJA4/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have the last `{` commented out by your `imgl.src=="images/mathewgarber.jpg"`).

Secondly, the `img1.src` gives you a different string, take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Nke/1/)

You should check for the src like this:

```
if(imgl.src.indexOf("images/joe2.jpg") > -1)
```